# Speedometer using CCP

Tags: microcontroller, pic, programming

I made a Speedometer using CCP pin as input. it works. but i have some problem. speed is changed frequently within a range, even using static frequency (When I use a static frequency, It should display fixed value). I used average speed(sum few pulse times and get average). then occurred another problem(when speed is slow, speed changing is delay). what is the wrong? My full code is bellow.

please, anybody can help me?

```c
//PIC - 16F648A Lang.- MikroC clock- Internal clock 4MHz
unsigned int speed;
unsigned short one_digit,ten_digit,hun_digit,overflow;
unsigned long one_pulse_time;
bit time_over,speed_change;
void calc_speed();
void ssdecode(int i);
void main() {
  CMCON = 0b00000111;
  TRISA = 0b0010000;
  TRISB = 0b0001000;
  INTCON = 0b11000000;
  T1CON = 0b00110011;        // Prescaler 1:8
  PIE1 = 0b00000101;
  PIR1 = 0b00000000;
  CCP1CON = 0b00000100;
  PIE1.CCP1IE  = 1 ;                  // enable CCP1 Interrupt
  PIR1.CCP1IF  = 0 ;                    // Clear CCP1 INTERRUPT Flag
  TMR1H        = 0 ;                    // reset Timer1
  TMR1L        = 0  ;
  PIR1.TMR1IF  = 0  ;                   // Timer1 Overflow Flag Cleared
  T1CON.TMR1ON = 1 ;
  speed_change = 0;
  one_pulse_time = 0;
  speed = 0;
  overflow = 0;
  do {
     if(speed_change==1) calc_speed();
     ssdecode(one_digit); //Display one's digit
     PORTA.F2 = 1;
     Delay_ms(2);
     PORTA.F2 = 0;
     ssdecode(ten_digit); //Display ten's digit
     PORTA.F3 = 1;
     Delay_ms(2);
     PORTA.F3 = 0;
     ssdecode(hun_digit); //Display hundred's digit
     PORTA.F4 = 1;
     Delay_ms(2);
     PORTA.F4 = 0;
  }while(1);
}
void interrupt()  {
  if(PIR1.TMR1IF)  {
     overflow++;
     PIR1.TMR1IF=0;
  }
  if (PIR1.CCP1IF) {// Check for Timer 0 interrupt
     if(overflow < 2) {
       one_pulse_time = overflow*65536;
       ccp1con = 0b00000000;
       one_pulse_time += CCPR1H*256 + CCPR1L;
       ccp1con = 0b00000100;
       time_over = 0;
     }
     else  time_over = 1;`

     overflow = 0;
     speed_change = 1;
     PIR1.TMR1IF=0;
     PIR1.CCP1IF = 0; // Clear RB0 interrupt flag
`  }
}`
`
void calc_speed() {
   if (time_over==0 && one_pulse_time > 0 ) {
      speed=(3600000*1.7)/(one_pulse_time*8); //   3.6*1000000 = kmh  , 1.7m = wheel circumference , (one_pulse_time*Prescaler)
      one_digit = speed%10;
      speed=speed/10;
      ten_digit = speed%10;
      hun_digit = speed/10;
      speed_change=0;
      one_pulse_time = 0;
   }
   else speed=0;
}
void ssdecode(int i)
{
   switch (i)
   {
      case 0: PORTB = 0b01111110; break;
      case 1: PORTB = 0b00001100; break;
      case 2: PORTB = 0b10110110; break;
      case 3: PORTB = 0b10011110; break;
      case 4: PORTB = 0b11001100; break;
      case 5: PORTB = 0b11011010; break;
      case 6: PORTB = 0b11111010; break;
      case 7: PORTB = 0b00001110; break;
      case 8: PORTB = 0b11111110; break;
      case 9: PORTB = 0b11011110; break;
   }
}
```

---

**update:**

I corrected it. It is working. I correct as this,

But I have another small problem. The 7SD is always shake and blink.I found the fault. it takes 3ms(approximately) for calc_Speed. how can I fix it? help me.

```c
void interrupt()  {
  if(PIR1.TMR1IF)  {
     overflow++;
     PIR1.TMR1IF=0;
  }
  if(overflow > 2) {
     time_over = 1;
     one_digit = 0; ten_digit = 0; hun_digit = 0;
  }
  if (PIR1.CCP1IF) {// Check for Timer 0 interrupt
     if(overflow < 3) {
       one_pulse_time_of = overflow*65536;
       PIE1.CCP1IE = 0;
       CCP1CON = 0b00000000;
       one_pulse_time = one_pulse_time_of + (CCPR1H*256 + CCPR1L);
       CCP1CON = 0b00000101;
       PIE1.CCP1IE = 1;
       time_over = 0;
     }
     else  time_over = 1;
     T1CON.TMR1ON = 0 ;
     CCP1CON = 0b00000000;
     CCPR1H=0x00;
     CCPR1L=0x00;
     CCP1CON = 0b00000101;
     TMR1H = 0x00 ;                   // Set initial value for the timer TMR1 for maximum counts available
     TMR1L = 0x00 ;
     overflow = 0;
     speed_change = 1;
     T1CON.TMR1ON = 1 ;
     PIR1.TMR1IF=0;
     PIR1.CCP1IF = 0; // Clear RB0 interrupt flag
  }
}
void calc_speed() {
   if ((time_over == 0) && (one_pulse_time > 0)) {
      speed=(3600000*1.8)/(one_pulse_time*8*5);       //  1.8m = wheel circumference , (one_pulse_time*Prescaler*pulse_per_revolution)
      one_digit = speed%10;
      speed=speed/10;
      ten_digit = speed%10;
      hun_digit = speed/10;
      speed_change=0;
      one_pulse_time = 0;
   }
   else {
      one_digit = 0; ten_digit = 0; hun_digit = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the value of the timer `TMR1H/L` is copied to the CPP register `CPPR1L/H` on an CPP event. This allows the timer to continue running while the code processes the CPP data.
So let's say you get a CPP interrupt when the timer value is 30.000. The next timer overflow will occur just 35.536 "timer-ticks" later, BUT you count this overflow as full 65566 tics.
You have to set the timer value to zero when an CPP interrupt occurs!

About your problem at low speed: You allow just one overflow for a valid reading (`if(overflow < 2)`) But what happens, if there is just one CPP event every 10 overflows? The overflow will be set to 0 on each CPP event, but on the next CPP event, overflow is again larger than 1.
You will never get a reading in this case! 
I guess you have mostly more than one, and sometimes less than one overflow between two CPP events (the timer problem may be a reason for this), so you get a reading only sometimes.